# empty p:dataTable only updates on second click on p:commandButton

Tags: ajax, primefaces, datatable

I have a shopping cart dataTable which is empty initially, adding an item does not update it dynamically (refreshing the page shows that item), but adding a second item will update the table and show both items that are added.

As a beginner, not quite sure what to provide but below are the most essential parts omitting the data output:

checkout.xhtml

```
<h:form id="formCart">
    <p:dataTable id="dataTableCart" widgetVar="dataTableCart" value="#{checkoutManagedBean.lineItems}" var="lineItem">
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
<h:form id="formAddToCart">
    <p:dialog id="dialogAddToCart" widgetVar="dialogAddToCart" header="Add to Cart" closable="true">
        <p:panelGrid>
            <p:commandButton value="Add to Cart" actionListener="#{checkoutManagedBean.addToCart}" update="@form formCart:dataTableCart" oncomplete="PF('dialogAddToCart').show();" />
        </p:panelGrid>
    </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

My CheckoutManagedBean addToCart method simply adds the lineItem to an array list of lineItems.

Would appreciate any help you can provide! Do let me know if I should include more details.

Comment: Wrap `p:dataTable` within `h:panelGroup` with a unique id and update that panel.

Comment: Sure you don't have any errors? Run your application in development mode... And try again. There must be an error somewere (due to the `update` attribibute containing wrong values

Comment: @ParkashKumar: not needed. There is a wrong value in the update attribute on the commandButton

Comment: @ParkashKumar tested that but did not work
@Kukeltje the application runs properly. Not sure what is the format for `update` attribute

Comment: I may have omitted too much, I am using ajax filtering in the `dataTable` and removing that solves this issue. Perhaps I am doing something wrong with the filtered list in the backend.